# Java socket based file transfer application client runs when being debugged but fails when run normally

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, debugging, watchservice

I have been given a assignment to create a Dropbox like file multi client single server file transfer application. So I created a Server application in java that runs continuously to accept connections from clients and give each client it's own thread so they can all work concurrently. The Clients on the other hand monitor a predesignated folder for any new file additions. As soon as they detect a new file they send it to server. When the server receives a file it will then send that file to all connected clients.

My PROBLEM is that the client code runs okay during debugging but when run normally it gives the error: 
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Distributed Systems\Labs\Lab_1\client_1\shared_directory\random.txt (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

after some debugging I realized that this error is happening because the client code is too fast and that's why I had to make it slow artificially by adding Thread.sleep().

What can I do to ensure that the client waits for the file to be properly added to the monitored folder before attempting to send it to the server ?.

I am using java.nio.file Watch Service API to monitor the folder for new or modified files.

The Serve code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class FT_Server {

    // Vector to store active clients
    static Vector<ClientHandler> connectedClients = new Vector<>();
    static ArrayList<String> clientNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String userName = "";

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(59898)) {
            System.out.println("Server is running, waiting for connection");

            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

            while (true) {
                //client socket created
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                //obtain input and output streams
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                userName = dis.readUTF();

                System.out.println(userName);

                // check if username already exists

                for (ClientHandler clt : FT_Server.connectedClients) {
                    clientNames.add(clt.cltName);
                }

                while (clientNames.contains(userName)) {
                    dos.writeUTF("FALSE");
                    userName = dis.readUTF();
                }

                dos.writeUTF("TRUE");

                System.out.println("Creating a new handler for this client...");

                // Create a new handler object for handling this request.
                ClientHandler clt = new ClientHandler(clientSocket, userName);

                //add the new client handler object to the vector of connected clients
                connectedClients.add(clt);
                clientNames.add(userName);

                System.out.println(connectedClients);
                System.out.println(clientNames);

                pool.execute(clt);
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    DataInputStream  dis       = null;
    DataOutputStream dos       = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    Socket           cltSocket;
    String           cltName;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    boolean isloggedin;

    ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket, String userName) {
        this.cltSocket = clientSocket;
        this.cltName = userName;
        this.isloggedin=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside ClientHandler class's run method");
        String fileName = "";
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while (true){
            try {
                // receive file from client
                dis = new DataInputStream(cltSocket.getInputStream());
                dos = new DataOutputStream(cltSocket.getOutputStream());

                if (dis != null)
                    System.out.println("dis not null");

                //get the name of the file
                fileName = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("fileName = "+fileName);

                if(fileName.equals("logout")){
                    this.isloggedin=false;
                    this.cltSocket.close();
                    break;
                }

                fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/Distributed Systems/Labs/Lab_1/server/" + fileName);

                //get the size of the file to be received
                long size = dis.readLong();
                System.out.println("size = "+size);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) size];

                //write the data bytes received to a file
                while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = dis.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    size -= bytesRead;
                }

                System.out.println("File " + fileName + " downloaded from client(" + size + " bytes read)");

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            //send the file to all the connected clients
            final String FILE_TO_SEND = "D:/Distributed Systems/Labs/Lab_1/server/" + fileName;

            try {
                System.out.println("inside sending file to connected clients try section");
                File myFile = new File(FILE_TO_SEND);
                byte[] fileContents = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                // disB = new DataInputStream(bis);

                if (bis != null){
                    System.out.println("bis not null");
                }

                //fill the data into the Byte array?
                bis.read(fileContents, 0, fileContents.length);

                // Sending file to each connected client
                for (ClientHandler clt : FT_Server.connectedClients) {
                    System.out.println("inside for loop");
                    if (clt.cltName != this.cltName && clt.isloggedin==true){
                        System.out.println("inside if");
                        //Send the file name to the client
                        clt.dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());

                        //send the length of the file to the client
                        clt.dos.writeLong(fileContents.length);

                        System.out.println("Sending the file" + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + fileContents.length + " bytes)");

                        //send the file contents to the client?
                        clt.dos.write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.length);
                        clt.dos.flush();

                        // // Sending file data to the client?
                        // os.write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.length);
                        // os.flush();
                        System.out.println("File sent to client = "+clt.cltName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e + "for client socket: " + cltSocket);
            }
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("inside finally");
            dis.close();
            dos.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
            bis.close();
            cltSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FT_Client_1 {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        FT_Client_1 clt = new FT_Client_1();

        clt.startConnection();

        clt.runClient();

//        clt.closeConnection();
    }

    public void runClient() {
        System.out.println("inside runClient()");
        //monitor the shared directory and send any new files to the server
        MonitorSharedDirectory mon = new MonitorSharedDirectory();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(mon);
        t1.start();

        // Receive any files sent by the server
        receiveFileFromServer rec = new receiveFileFromServer();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(rec);
        t2.start();
    }

    public void startConnection() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println("inside startConnection()");
        String username = "";
        Boolean valid = true;

        // taking username as input from the user
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a username:");
        username = sc.nextLine();

        //creating client socket
        clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 59898);

        //getting the data input and output stream using client socket
        dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        dos.writeUTF(username);
        System.out.println("after sending username to the server");

        // Checking if server accepted the username
        do {
            String serverReply = dis.readUTF();
            if (serverReply == "FALSE"){
                // disconnect from server socket TODO
                System.out.println("Given Username is already in use, please provide another Username");
                username = sc.nextLine();
                dos.writeUTF(username);
            }else {
                valid = false;
            }
        }while (valid);

        System.out.println("after while loop to check if username is unique");
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("client " + username + " has been connected to the server");
    }

    public class MonitorSharedDirectory implements Runnable {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("inside MonitorSharedDirectory class's run method");

            try{
                System.out.println("inside MonitorSharedDirectory try section");

                Path watchFolder = Paths.get("D:/Distributed Systems/Labs/Lab_1/client_1/shared_directory/");
                WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
                watchFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY); //add ENTRY_MODIFY to this to monitor for file modifications

                boolean valid = true;

                do {
                    WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

                    for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {

                        WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(kind) || StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY.equals(kind)) {
                            String fileName = event.context().toString();
                            System.out.println("File Created:" + fileName);

                            int attempts = 0;
                            while(dis.available() == 0 && attempts < 1000)
                            {
                                attempts++;
                                Thread.sleep(5);
                            }

                            // sending new file to server
                            File myFile = new File("D:/Distributed Systems/Labs/Lab_1/client_1/shared_directory/" + fileName);
                            byte[] fileContents = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                            fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

                            dis.readFully(fileContents, 0, fileContents.length);

                            dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
                            dos.writeLong(fileContents.length);
                            dos.write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.length);
                            dos.flush();
                            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" sent to Server.");


//                            //fill the data into the Byte array?
//                            bis.read(fileContents, 0, fileContents.length);
//
//                            dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
//
//                            //send the length of the file to the client
//                            dos.writeLong(fileContents.length);
//
//                            System.out.println("Sending the file " + myFile + " (" + fileContents.length + " bytes)");
//
//                            //send the file contents to the server?
//                            dos.write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.length);
//                            dos.flush();

                            if (fis != null)
                                fis.close();
                            if (bis != null)
                                bis.close();
                            if (dis != null)
                                dis.close();
                        }
                    }
                    valid = watchKey.reset();
                } while (valid);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error Prem: " + e );
            }finally {
                //if (dos != null)
                //dos.close();
                try {
                    if (fis != null)
                        fis.close();
                    if (bis != null)
                        bis.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class receiveFileFromServer implements Runnable {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("inside receiveFileFromServer class's run method");

            while (true){
                try {
                    System.out.println("inside receiveFileFromServer try section");

                    // receive file from server
                    String fileName = dis.readUTF();

                    System.out.println(fileName);

                    fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/Distributed Systems/Labs/Lab_1/client_1/shared_directory/" + fileName);

                    int bytesRead = 0;

                    long size = dis.readLong();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) size];

                    while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = dis.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        size -= bytesRead;
                    }
                    System.out.println("File " + fileName + " downloaded from server(" + size + " bytes read)");

                    if (fos != null)
                        fos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("inside closeConnection()");
        if (dis != null)
            dis.close();
        if (dos != null)
            dos.close();
        if (clientSocket != null)
            clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==` or `!=`: use `equals()`. Your `valid` flag is back to front in the client. `if (dis != null)` is impossible: if the stream couldn't be created you would have got an exception.

Answer (score 0):

easy approach- you could handle that by keeping a register of the files in small dB on server with file stamp and file size we call it metadata.

This way in case the file is changed in future and sent over second time with changed content, you could look up the metadata.

If the same file sent over to server, server rejects the file and it will not be propagated to other clients.

In my case I was using aws sqs, and I looked up message ids to check duplicate files.

I hope this approach helps.

Answer (score -1):

I faced exact same problem while writing an inventory application with watcher and create event. rather adding thread sleep and counter in loop, I would watch the file size if it keeps changing. There is code available for this in on google. It works like charm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Amol, I am facing another issue such that whenever a new file is created in one clients folder say by client-1, that file gets sent to the server and the server sends it to the other client say client-2, but then the watcher at client 2 registers the file sent by the server as a new file and sends it back to the server. This ends up creating a infinite loop of the same file being sent again and again, how do I prevent this?